# Chaining shortcuts into one shortcut

Tags: macos, mac, catalina

Basically, I want to chain arbitrary commands sequentially into one command: `⌘+R` `⌘+S` `⌘+W` all into a custom shortcut `^+R` Is there a way to do this natively on mac? If not, is there an application that can do that for me?

Using a MacBook Pro running Catalina 10.15.6

Comment: Keyboard Maestro is what you want.

Comment: @benwiggy thanks! Just what I needed!